# How can I create 1 hour tar.gz files based on the timestamp in filename?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I have many folders (e.g. /input_dir/data/prod/2023/01/31/) which each contain files of the following form:

1. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T000000Z_e20230131T000400Z_v1-0-2.fits
2. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T000400Z_e20230131T000800Z_v1-0-2.fits
3. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T000800Z_e20230131T001200Z_v1-0-2.fits
4. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T010000Z_e20230131T010400Z_v1-0-2.fits
5. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T010400Z_e20230131T010800Z_v1-0-2.fits
6. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T010800Z_e20230131T011200Z_v1-0-2.fits
7. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T011200Z_e20230131T011600Z_v1-0-2.fits
8. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T011600Z_e20230131T012000Z_v1-0-2.fits
   ...
9. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T234400Z_e20230131T234800Z_v1-0-2.fits
10. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T234800Z_e20230131T235200Z_v1-0-2.fits
11. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T235200Z_e20230131T235600Z_v1-0-2.fits
12. ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T235600Z_e20230201T000000Z_v1-0-2.fits

The s20230131T000000Z and e20230131T000400Z portions are the start/end time each file covers, where the timestamps are in the form "YYYYMMDD T HHMMSS Z". I would like to create a new output directory for each day with files aggregated into 24 separate tar.gz files which each contain all the files created during the same hour.

For example, in the above list files 1-3 would be tarred and gzipped into a single file for hour zero: ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T000000Z_e20230131T005959.tar.gz . Files 4-8 would be tarred into the 01 hour: ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T010000Z_e20230131T015959.tar.gz. And 9-12 output to hour 23: ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s20230131T234400Z_e20230131T235959.tar.gz. These would all go to a new output directory /output_dir/data/prod_version/2023/01/31/

I have created a Python script which generates a pandas dataframe, but I'm not sure how to extract just the groupings I seek in order to do the actual tar/gz.

Thanks in advance!

```
    def make_df(self):
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'Source':self.sourcePath,
             'Target': self.targetDir,
             'File': self.files,
             'Start': self.startTime
           })
        group1 = df.groupby(['Source', pd.Grouper(key='Start', freq = 'H')]).count()
        print(group1)
```

This outputs:

```
Source                                                          Start
/input_dir/data/prod/2022/10/10/                                2022-10-10 00:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 01:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 02:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 03:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 04:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 05:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 06:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 07:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 08:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 09:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 10:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 11:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 12:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 13:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 14:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 15:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 16:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 17:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 18:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 19:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 20:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 21:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 22:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 23:00:00      15    15

/input_dir/data/prod/2022/10/10/                                2022-10-10 00:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 01:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 02:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 03:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 04:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 05:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 06:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 07:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 08:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 09:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 10:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 11:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 12:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 13:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 14:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 15:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 16:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 17:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 18:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 19:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 20:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 21:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 22:00:00      15    15
                                                                2022-10-10 23:00:00      15    15
```

The output I would like is the actual files that are in each hourly group, not the number of them. I'm so close!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import tarfile

class FileAggregator:
    def __init__(self, source_path, target_dir, files, start_times):
        self.sourcePath = source_path
        self.targetDir = target_dir
        self.files = files
        self.startTime = start_times

    def output_filename(self, start_time):
        start = start_time.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
        end = (start_time + pd.Timedelta("59m59s")).strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
        return f"ops_inst-l2-prod_g16_s{start}_e{end}.tar.gz"

    def tar_and_gzip_files(self, output_path, file_list):
        with tarfile.open(output_path, "w:gz") as tar:
            for file in file_list:
                tar.add(os.path.join(self.sourcePath, file), arcname=file)

    def make_df(self):
        pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "Source": self.sourcePath,
                "Target": self.targetDir,
                "File": self.files,
                "Start": self.startTime,
            }
        )
        grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Start", freq="H"))

        for _, group in grouped:
            if not group.empty:
                output_path = os.path.join(self.targetDir, self.output_filename(group["Start"].iloc[0]))
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_path), exist_ok=True)
                self.tar_and_gzip_files(output_path, group["File"].tolist())

# Example usage:
source_path = "/input_dir/data/prod/2023/01/31/"
target_dir = "/output_dir/data/prod_version/2023/01/31/"

files = [ ... ]  # list of all file names
start_times = [pd.Timestamp(f[22:37].replace("T", " ")) for f in files]

aggregator = FileAggregator(source_path, target_dir, files, start_times)
aggregator.make_df()
```